# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: jquery, node.js

Здравствуйте!
Проблема при обработке AJAX-запроса на сервер

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Код AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data)
        this.setState({data: json});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err, data) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

Код сервера:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    var req = request.url;

    fs.readFile(req, function (err, data) {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" });
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
    });

}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: похоже, что сервер возвращает HTML. Приведите содержание ответа сервера.

Comment: Что в `data`? Явно `HTML`, а заголовок `Content-Type` говорит что это `JSON`, поэтому браузер пытается парсить содержимое как `JSON`, а в нём нет `<` вне строк.

Comment: Вывел ответ сервера, он возвращает содержимое index.html

http://prntscr.com/bqizqa

Comment: Поместите ответ сервера (`data`) в Ваш вопрос. Точнее решённый вопрос - содержимое не является валидным `JSON` форматом, это нельзя отдавать с `application/json`.